# RealmObjectSchema.removePrimaryKey and columnIndex is less than 0

Tags: android, realm

I have a model `ModelA` whicch is part of two `RealmModules`. In one `RealmModule` I want the model to have a primary key and other one I don't. So I am trying to remove primary key from a model when android app starts.And did

And did I mentioned that in one module this model i.e `ModelA` acts as parent model and in other its role is of a child of child model i.e ModelC -> ModelB -> ModelA

Here are the code snippets:

```
    public class ModelA extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id; 

    @Required
    private String name; 

    //public getters and setters 
}
```

And In other `RealmModule` I have ModelB and ModelC which are something like this :

```
public class ModelB extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    ModelA childModelA;

    //public getters and setters
}


public class ModelC extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    ModelB childModelB;

    //public getters and setters
}
```

And the modules themselves look like :

```
@RealmModule(classes = {
        ModelA.class
 } , library = true)
public class SmallModule{}




   @RealmModule(classes = {
            ModelA.class,
            ModelB.class,
            ModelC.class,
} , library = true)
    public class BigModule{}
```

This is how I am trying to remove the PrimaryKey from ModelA when schema/module is `BigModule`

```
 final RealmObjectSchema objectSchema = realmSchema.get(ModelA.class.getSimpleName());

realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            objectSchema.removePrimaryKey();
objectSchema.addIndex("id");
                    });
```

So far so good .. When I try to copy/update to realm in `SmallModule`, it works just fine. But as soon as I try to do same on `BigModule` this is what I get:

```
04-10 21:49:17.002 12946-13321/org.jay.test1.debug E/REALM_JNI: jni: ThrowingException 2, columnIndex is less than 0., .
        04-10 21:49:17.002 12946-13321/org.jay.test1.debug E/REALM_JNI: Exception has been throw: columnIndex is less than 0.
        04-10 21:49:17.017 12946-12946/org.jay.test1.debug V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{943b8b0 VFED..... .F....ID 0,0-480,800 #7f110086 app:id/drawer_layout} softInputMode=19 first=false flags=#81810100
        04-10 21:49:17.017 12946-12946/org.jay.test1.debug V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{943b8b0 VFED..... .F....ID 0,0-480,800 #7f110086 app:id/drawer_layout} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@c1bce40 controlFlags=#101
        04-10 21:49:17.043 12946-12946/org.jay.test1.debug E/DBHelper: [main::1] Error while inserting record
        04-10 21:49:17.045 12946-12946/org.jay.test1.debug E/DBHelper: [main::1] Subscriber Error::columnIndex is less than 0.
        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: columnIndex is less than 0.
        at io.realm.internal.Table.nativeFindFirstInt(Native Method)
        at io.realm.internal.Table.findFirstLong(Table.java:1077)
        at io.realm.ModelARealmProxy.copyOrUpdate(ModelARealmProxy.java:965)
        at io.realm.ModelBRealmProxy.copy(ModelBRealmProxy.java:810)
        at io.realm.ModelBRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate(ModelBRealmProxy.java:779)
        at io.realm.ModelCRealmProxy.copy(ModelCRealmProxy.java:1183)
        at io.realm.ModelCRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate(ModelCRealmProxy.java:1136)
        at io.realm.BigModuleMediator.copyOrUpdate(BigModuleMediator.java:370)
        at io.realm.Realm.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java:1505)
        at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Realm.java:953)
        at org.jay.test1.DBHelper$1$1.execute(DBHelper.java:66)
        at io.realm.Realm$1.run(Realm.java:1402)
        at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run(BgPriorityRunnable.java:34)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Realm is 2.3.1**

Comment: You should definitely file an issue here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues and provide a minimal example that reproduces this

Comment: It seems you are changing the schema out of the migration block? If you are doing that, something surely would be going wrong. Since all the column indexes are cached when the first time the typed realm opened, and the schema changes won't be reflected to the typed Realm anymore. May I ask why do you need to do this?

Comment: @beender There are two schema and only one of them need to have primary keys. I need to copy over from one schema to other in ordedr to maintain history. So if there is Primarykey and I do insertOrUpdate it overwrites the previous record, which beat the purpose of maintaing history. And if i try to do insert it throws exception.
And yes this is done out of migration block. PrmaryKey removal is executed when MainActivity is created.

Comment: @Beendar IS there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, you have the `id` defined as the PK in the Object, but since your data comes from JSON may have duplicated values, then you cannot use it as PK, so you want to remove it, right? Why don't you just remove the `@PrimaryKey` from the object definition? If you still need both, i suggest your to have both `int pkId` and `int id` defined in the Object. Then compute the `pkId` from your json value to make it unique.

Answer (score 0):

@Beender has this exactly right.  When you change the schema lots of things, including the numberings of the columns, can change.  As he says: Since all the column indexes are cached the first time the typed realm opened, subsequent schema changes won't be reflected.

I think you should not be fiddling with your schema to try to shoehorn weird data into the DB.  If you have data that you want to store, that is *not* a primary key, make a place for it in your schema, but don't attempt to use it as a primary key.